# Learn geological properties of the horizon through density of the rocks

Tags: tectonics, gravity, horizon

It is possible to evaluate the geological structure of a basin based on gravimetric data. But if one doesn't have gravimetric data, how can one learn the geological structure and properties of a certain horizon in the basin according to the density of rocks?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a homework question?  Generally those type of questions won't get answers unless the poster at least tries to give some of your own thinking towards it as well.